# how can write bind mount, volume mount in docker-compose's SHORT SYNTAX( version 3)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm confusing whether it's bind mount or volume mount when using docker-compose

for example

I think this compose bind mount on host

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
```

this compose volume mount

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  mysql:
```

it is right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes :-)

And I need this to make the answer long enough!